# python split statement for two string expressions

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have to parse a file in which there are some expressions such as:

```
(COMM_MINFULLCOMTIMEOFCHANNEL == "STD_ON" || COMM_NMLIGHTDURATIONOFCHANNEL == "STD_ON" || COMM_NMLIGHTSILENTDURATIONOFCHANNEL == "STD_ON")
```

i have parsed the expressions separately but when i have an expression like:

```
(COMM_MINFULLCOMTIMEOFCHANNEL == "STD_ON" || COMM_NMLIGHTDURATIONOFCHANNEL == "STD_ON" || COMM_NMLIGHTSILENTDURATIONOFCHANNEL == "STD_ON") => COMM_KEEP_AWAKE_CHANNELS_SUPPORT == "STD_ON"
```

it shows me an error because i haven't handles the "=>" implies sign. To handle this i have to split these expressions i think, but i dont know how to do that. Please help!!1 Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show your code and the error.

Comment: There is no error because i haven't done it yet i just know the concept.

Comment: At least you could  show what result you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using regexps.
Here's an example that matches all of your blocks:

```
import re
"""
whatever code
"""
tokens=re.findall(r"([\w\s\=\"]{3,})",line)
"""
whatever code
"""
```